# KerasでVGG16の転移学習をするときにValueErrorが発生する

Tags: python, python3, 機械学習, 深層学習, keras

### 質問

Kerasに実装されているVGG16を転移学習して画像の2クラス分類をしようと考えております。
[参考サイト](https://qiita.com/yottyann1221/items/20a9c8a7a02edc7cd3d1)のコードを一部修正して実行すると、下記エラーが発生して学習できません。

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected sequential_1 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

どのようにコードを修正すればよいでしょうか?
もしくは、教師データの数量が原因でしょうか?

### 現状

#### コード

```py
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Input, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense


n_categories = 2
batch_size = 2
train_data_dir = './images/train'
validation_data_dir = './images/validation'
file_name = 'vgg16_ano_fine'
image_size = 224

#画像データの水増しはしない
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    horizontal_flip=False)


test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(image_size, image_size),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

#2クラス分類のため'binary'を指定
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(image_size, image_size),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')


# VGG16のロード。FC層は不要なので include_top=False
input_tensor = Input(shape=(image_size, image_size, 3))
vgg16 = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=input_tensor)

# VGG16の図の緑色の部分（FC層）の作成
top_model = Sequential()
top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=vgg16.output_shape[1:]))
top_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
top_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
top_model.add(Dense(n_categories, activation='softmax'))

# VGG16とFC層を結合してモデルを作成（完成図が上の図）
model = Model(input=vgg16.input, output=top_model(vgg16.output))

# VGG16の図の青色の部分は重みを固定（frozen）
for layer in model.layers[:15]:
    layer.trainable = False
model.summary()
# 多クラス分類を指定
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-5, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=10 // batch_size,
    epochs=20,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=6 // batch_size)
```

#### 環境

- Windows10 1903
- python    v3.7.5
- keras-gpu v2.2.4
- keras     v2.2.4
- tensorflow v1.15.0
- cuddn     v10.0

#### 学習画像

クラスAとクラスBで、教師データがそれぞれ10枚、バリデーションデータがそれぞれ6枚。
画像サイズは224x224
実行時に下記のメッセージが出力されるため、画像読み込みはできていると思います。

```
Found 20 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 12 images belonging to 2 classes.
```

#### ネットワーク図

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 224, 224, 3)       0
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 56, 56, 128)       0
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 28, 28, 256)       0
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 14, 14, 512)       0
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 7, 7, 512)         0
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_1 (Sequential)    (None, 2)                 6423298
=================================================================
Total params: 21,137,986
Trainable params: 13,502,722
Non-trainable params: 7,635,264
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2クラス分類なら

```py
n_categories = 2
・・・
top_model.add(Dense(n_categories, activation='softmax'))
```

ではなく、

```py
n_categories = 1
・・・
top_model.add(Dense(n_categories, activation='softmax'))
```

では。